# RelativeLayout - positioning the text items in android

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout, textview, android

I have a listview that gets few columns from the database, and populates text views withing the listview... But i have a problem which results in the item overlapping...
Here is what i am trying to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR5Jp.jpg

The bolded text is gonna be static (taken from @string), while the grey text should be taken from the database, which text might be just one or much more words..
My .xml file for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idTender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textView2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/textView3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="" />  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/textView3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried many ways, by using the android:layout's like bellow, alignleft and testing with others.. But i could not manage to find the logic behind this designing..

So if you can help me to build this layout it would be very nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels on the left should be horizontally aligned to each other, or with the same margin from the left screen border. Each value label should align horizontally to the right of the label. The key point in vertical alignment to avoid overlapping is that you align each label to be below the previous value, not the previous label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Number:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="myNumber"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Text1:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="long text is long is long text long is text is very very long text is long text long is indeed very long text even longer than what you would expect"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Text2:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Yay this is in the right position"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Layout]